# How can I join three tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is not joining the three tables in SQL Server.

Code:

```
    SELECT Ledger.ledger_id,
           Ledger.std_reg_id,
           Ledger.fee_of_month,
           Ledger.ledger_date,
           Ledger.fees,
           Other_Fees.other_fees_id,
           Other_Fees.title
    FROM Ledger
    INNER JOIN Other_Fees
           ON Ledger.other_fees_id = Other_Fees.other_fees_id
    INNER JOIN Std_Profile
           ON Ledger.std_reg_id = Std_Profile.std_reg_id
```

Comment: What error does it say?

Comment: T-SQL statement seems fine - what do you mean by *is not joining* ? Are you getting an ERROR? IF so: what error? Are you just not getting any data? Well - are you **SURE** that there are rows in all the three tables that **match** these join criteria?

Comment: @Tanner "Dude" what does mine say?

Comment: Well, if you get `Null` - then there **are no rows** in your tables that match this set of criteria! Plain and simple .... there are no rows in `Other_Fees` where their `other_fees_id` matches `Ledger.other_fees_id` - or there are no rows in `Std_Profile` where `std_reg_id` matches `Ledger.std_reg_id`. Check for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **INNER JOIN** will only return records that match in both tables.  It's possible that between the 3 tables, there's no identically matching data.  Try using a **LEFT JOIN** and see if it returns anything.  By using a **LEFT JOIN**, you should at least get everything back from dbo.Ledger.

Also, you should probably alias your tables like such:

```
SELECT 
   L.ledger_id,
   L.std_reg_id,
   L.fee_of_month,
   L.ledger_date,
   L.fees,
   F.other_fees_id,
   F.title
FROM dbo.Ledger L
LEFT JOIN dbo.Other_Fees F
ON L.other_fees_id = F.other_fees_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Std_Profile P
ON L.std_reg_id = P.std_reg_id
```